# format string to json / dict

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have a string that has the following contents:

```
print("json str:", type(json_str), json_str)
        
json str: <class 'str'> json

{
    "word": [
        "table name"
    ]
}
```

I get an exception when I attempt to run:

```
import json

json.loads(json_str).get('word')
```

How do I format the string, such that I can call `.get` method?

```
Exception Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: So, your string is literally `json  {"word":["table name"]}`? That's not valid json...How do you produce it?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah, need to remove the extra `json` and format as json string. It's an API response.

Comment: You can try `print(json.loads(json_str[4:]).get('word'))`

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the leading text to the actual json string:

```py
import json
import string

input_string = input_string.strip(string.ascii_letters)
data = json.loads(input_string)
```